# Display image from database as a cell in a table

Tags: php, mysql

So I was implementing a sponsorship admin website then I encountered some trouble around.I am aware that storing image into database could be such pain in the neck but this is required(having a filesystem to store images in the campus server is prohibited).

I create 3 tables:

- a info table storing text information,
- an image table storing images in BLOB fashion and
- a id_table table as a reference table keeping records of image id and info id.

```php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT info_id,info_name,info_year,info_level,info_email,info_describe FROM info");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<td>" . $row['info_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['info_year'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['info_level' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['info_email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['info_describe'] . "</td>";
    $result_image_id = mysql_query("SELECT id_image FROM id_table WHERE id_info = '{$row['info_id']}'");
    $row_image = mysql_fetch_array($result_image_id);
    $result_image = mysql_query("SELECT image_stuff FROM image WHERE image_id = '{$row_image['id_image']}'");
    $row_2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_image);
    $content=$row_2['image_stuff'];
    echo "<td>" ;
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $content;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then in the browser, I was redirected to a blank page. If I delete that header function, I do have a table in the page but there is nothing in the image column.

Any suggestions ?

Additionally, I tried using an `<img>` tag in my while loop:

```
echo "<img src='$content' />";
```

The good news is, it kind of worked out but the image file did not display practically.

I had a table in my page with image column filled with image files, but it looked just like the server did not find the image though.

I guess there does not exist any problem with my insert script because when I was applying that img tag,the "cannot display" logo only appeared in the cell whose row is the one I did upload image file into database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use headers like that...

try something like that

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT info_id,info_name,info_year,info_level,info_email,info_describe FROM info");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<td>" . $row['info_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['info_year'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['info_level' ] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['info_email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['info_describe'] . "</td>";
$result_image_id = mysql_query("SELECT id_image FROM id_table WHERE id_info = '{$row['info_id']}'");
$row_image = mysql_fetch_array($result_image_id);
$result_image = mysql_query("SELECT image_stuff FROM image WHERE image_id = '{$row_image['id_image']}'");
$row_2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_image);
$content=$row_2['image_stuff'];
echo "<td>" ;
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($content) . '" />';
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Change the png for whatever type of image you stored. I havent looked at the code much but this should work.

Comment: if I didnt encode $content,I would get like http://localhost/project_name/Array as the URL of an arbitrary image.An "cant be displayed" logo stuff appeared in image column.Is it possible that there is anything wrong in my image insertation script?

Comment: `base64_encode()` is a bandwidth hog as you take a binary image and convert it to ASCII characters!  Why not save the image to disk or better yet not store the binary image in the database?  Store the path to the binary image on your filesystem that is web accessible.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez "(having a filesystem to store images in the campus server is prohibited)" Quoted from OP.

Comment: $sql_2="INSERT INTO image (image_id,image_name,image_stuff)
    VALUES (NULL, '$_FILES[file][name]',    '$_FILES[file]');";
  if (!mysql_query($sql_2,$con))
  {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

Comment: I omitted other parts,like judging if the file type is legal and stuff.

Comment: This wont store the image data... try
                $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); and replace $_FILES[file] by $data in your insert query

Comment: @holycowbatman you can store them off-site.  There are plenty of free image sites you can link directly to.  They are happy to provide you free bandwidth.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

echo "" . $row ['post_image'] . ""

Comment: Please explain how this can help question author?